# Collapsible navigation bar issues

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navigation bar similar to [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). If you go to their site and re-size your browser. if you re-size it narrow enough, the top navigation bar will become a button. when you click on the button, it pushes everything down and displays the full navigation again.

That's what I'm trying to accomplish with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMdYg/4/), but it has the following issues:

1. initially, the button is not hidden, it should be hidden and only be visible when the screen gets too narrow.
2. (fixed) the button doesn't display background like bootstrap does
3. (fixed) re-size browser to make navigation disappear and click on the button. then click on sub menu, the sub menu items does not display well.

issue 1 screen prints:

nav bar should not be visible yet because browser width is larger than 940px
[image: nav bar should not be visible yet because browser width is larger than 940px]

nav bar appears, it's fine because browser width is less than 940px
[image: nav bar appears, it's fine because browser width is less than 940px]

**full html code:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {    
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conatiner-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span10">

                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                href="#">Help<b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Keep</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Screaming</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span10">
                other content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this closer to what you are after?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/R4BEY/

You have a span10 div in your example and I didn't know where you were heading with this so I added a span2 after it to complete the row.

The HTML is below. You had a typo on your opening container div, and you were missing the navbar and navbar-inner divs. I think that was it for the changes I made.

Good luck

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span10">

<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">


<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </a>

 <div class="nav-collapse collapse ">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Help<b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Keep</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Screaming</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- end nav-collapse -->

 </div><!-- end nav bar inner -->  
 </div> <!-- end nav bar -->

</div><!--end span10 -->
<div class="span2">span 2</div>
</div><!-- end row -->


<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span10">
  other content
</div>
<div class="span2">span 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but it only fixes issue #2 and 3, not #1. For #1, I like the links to show and only when the browser window gets narrow, it collapses into a button. I created another fiddle from your updates. http://jsfiddle.net/qMdYg/4/

Comment: By default the Bootstrap menu collapses at 940px, which is what's happening in my example and on the Bootstrap site. Are you wanting to change this break point?

Comment: I included screen prints to demonstrate issue 1.

Comment: Ray, could you double check my jsFiddle again? Unless I'm missing something obvious, I don't see the issue that you have, so maybe I had forgotten to update my version: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/R4BEY/